# Jenkins build failed - ZAP PATH IS MISSING, PROVIDED

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, zap

i have tried to integrate ZAP with jenkins and  for that i have refer the video in the below path.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

When i build my jenkins job,ended with below error.Can any one help me for this issue.Appreciate your quick response and thanks for giving your valuable time.

**[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] START BUILD STEP [ZAP Jenkins Plugin] PLUGIN VALIDATION (PLG), VARIABLE VALIDATION AND ENVIRONMENT INJECTOR EXPANSION (EXP) ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ZAP PATH IS MISSING, PROVIDED [ null ] at org.jenkinsci.plugins.zap.ZAPDriver.checkParams(ZAPDriver.java:488) at org.jenkinsci.plugins.zap.ZAPDriver.startZAP(ZAPDriver.java:592) at org.jenkinsci.plugins.zap.ZAPBuilder.perform(ZAPBuilder.java:281) at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20) at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:939) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:890) at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534) at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544) at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98) at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405) Build step 'Execute ZAP' marked build as failure channel stopped Archiving artifacts [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports... [htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST_ZAP/reports to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST_ZAP/htmlreports/Last_Vulnerability_Report ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST_ZAP/reports' does not exist. Finished: FAILURE**

Comment: Might be worth asking that on the ZAP Jenkins User Group: https://github.com/jenkinsci/zap-plugin

Comment: Please fill out a support ticket on the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/zaproxy-jenkins